# Starting monerod v0.11.1 Exception in main! Failed to initialize p2p server. Failed to deinitialize core

Tags: monerod, linux

I'm on ubuntu 14.4 and monero used to work, but now I'm getting the following error. I'm not sure how to fix this.

```
2017-12-21 17:04:20.897     7fe75c63a780    INFO    global  src/daemon/main.cpp:279 Monero 'Helium Hydra' (v0.11.1.0-release)
2017-12-21 17:04:20.898     7fe75c63a780    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:55    Initializing cryptonote protocol...
2017-12-21 17:04:20.898     7fe75c63a780    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:60    Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
2017-12-21 17:04:20.906     7fe75c63a780    INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:63 Initializing p2p server...
2017-12-21 17:04:21.767     7fe75c63a780    INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:89    Deinitializing core...
2017-12-21 17:04:21.771     7fe75c63a780    ERROR   daemon  src/daemon/core.h:94    Failed to deinitialize core...
2017-12-21 17:04:21.781     7fe75c63a780    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:77    Stopping cryptonote protocol...
2017-12-21 17:04:21.781     7fe75c63a780    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:81    Cryptonote protocol stopped successfully
2017-12-21 17:04:21.781     7fe75c63a780    ERROR   daemon  src/daemon/main.cpp:287 Exception in main! Failed to initialize p2p server.
```

Comment: Check whether you don't already have a `monerod` running.

Comment: yes that fixed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you don't have another monerod service running. I had to kill mine and start it again to get it to work.

- `ps -aux | grep monero`
- `kill < id >`

Get the id from `ps` and then kill it.